# Binary Serialization of Class with Observable Collection Fails

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, observablecollection

- FINAL UPDATE:  Here's what the real issue was, the solution, and a good article to read:

The problem was what one of the classes being serialized had an event.  The solution was to place a [field:NonSerialized] in front of the event declaration.  I was referred to the following article:

[Format Your Way to Success with the .NET Framework ...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2004/october/successful-formatting-in-net-framework-versions-1-1-and-2-0#S1)

Thanks to Microsoft for solving *

- This issue is being investigated by Microsoft.  At this point, it is not clear whether the problem is with ObservableCollection or something else.  Thanks to all who responded. *

I added an ObservableCollection to my serializable class. When I attempt to write it out to a binary file, an exception is thrown. Using VS 2019 version 16.7.3 and .NET 4.8.04084.

I get the following error message at the UI:

Error: Type 'System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager' in Assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.

This looks like a problem that was talked about at least 8 years ago and was reported to have been fixed by .NET 4.0.  But obviously, I am running into it now.  Does anyone know how to get around this for binary serialization?  I have to use ObservableCollection for binding purposes.

Thanks.

Comment: _"This looks like a problem that was talked about"_ -- please cite the references you use to justify that statement. _"obviously, I am running into it now"_ -- nothing is obvious if you don't show us. Please include a [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: It would actually be quite surprising to me if anyone had undertaken the effort to make `ObservableCollection` serializable, and it certainly won't be happening now, since binary serialization is deprecated for most scenarios. The simplest workaround would be to serialize something else -- you don't need to serialize the `ObservableCollection` as an actual observable collection, just serialize it as an array (and on serializing back, initialize the collection with that).